# How to build an array for a WP_User_Query

Tags: php, custom-wordpress-pages

I have an array:

```
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'meta_key' => $columnName,
    'order' => $columnOrder,
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'shipping_company',
            'value' => '^'.$prospectSearch,
            'compare' => 'REGEXP',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'shipping_company',
            'value' => '---NV',
            'compare' => 'NOT LIKE',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'shipping_company',
            'value' => '---DS',
            'compare' => 'NOT LIKE',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'customer_status',
            'value' => '1',
            'compare' => '=',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Along with that I also need to search the user_meta table for many many zip codes in a loop like this:

```
$args['meta_query'][]=array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
);

foreach($zips as $zip) {
    $args['meta_query'][]=array(
        array(
            'key' => 'shipping_postcode',
            'value' => $zip,
            'compare' => '=',
        ),
    );
}
```

The problem is that the 'OR' in the zip code portion always gets changed to an 'AND'. I feed this array to WP_User_Query like this:

`$wpUserQuery = new WP_User_Query($args);`

I use the following line to get the SQL:

`$wpUserQuery->request;`

Comment: the 'relation' => 'OR', should be inside the `$args['meta_query'][]=array('relation' => 'OR', array(`, its OR on the items in the loop, it will default to AND see: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_meta_query/#comment-1989

Comment: Thank you for the link. I have followed that model. It works great if I build it statically, but since I have so many zip codes to work with I need to build it in a loop somehow. That's where I struggle.

Comment: yeep, like https://3v4l.org/Qe0Q6 if not what you want then put expected array up and ill tweak it.

Comment: hhmmm. It appears that if I go to line 39 and change the AND to an OR it looks like the generated SQL is correct. However, when I copy paste the SQL into phpmyadmin it is very large and won't run. I had to restart php to end the process. Perhaps this plan won't work and I need to create a temp table in mysql, populated it, search it and finally delete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went a different route. Rather than using WP_User_Query I am going the build the SQL string manually and optimize it.